# pass arguments of a python script from a powershell script

Tags: python, powershell

I have a python script as given below

```
mypython.py -m Filename -i Filepath
```

i want to execute this python script from a powershell script.

i tried the following

```
$myscript='$filepath\mypython.py'
$myargs="-m Filename -i Filepath"
& python.exe $myscript $myargs
```

But  getting an error from mypython.py which says all arguments are not supplied

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself

just pass the argument like below

```
& python.exe $myscript -m "Filename" -i "Filepath"
```

This will solve the issue